# Why is background-repeat property used in carousel-control class of Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the `carousel-control` background gradient is already applied from left to right. Then what is the purpose of using `background-repeat: repeat-x`? Nor is there any image applied to the background of `carousel-control` buttons.

Comment: remove it and see what happens?

Comment: @Jhecht Nothing happens. Everything remains the same.

Comment: then the answer is "there isn't a good reason."